# Rename files in a subfolder with subfolder tag

Tags: python

Currently I have 38 subfolders in my folder **test** The sub folder names start from **01** to **38**. Each sub folder has 2 wav files which are named randomly I want to rename it properly and sequentially.
for example:
sub folder **01** has wav files **My recording #1** and **My recording #6** , I want them to be renamed as **01_test_01** and **01_test_02** so the last folder **38** should have files **38_test_01** and **38_test_02**

below is my code

```
import os
name = 'test'

rootdir = r'C:\Users\kushal\Desktop\final_earthquake\demonstration_sikkim\wav\test'

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:

        filepath = subdir+os.sep +file
        if filepath.endswith('.wav'):

            split_dir = subdir.split(os.sep)

            f_name, f_ext=(os.path.splitext(file))

            new_1 = split_dir[8]
            y=1
            while y < 3 :
              new_name= (new_1 +'_' + 'test_' + str(y).zfill(2) + f_ext)
              y = y +1
              print (filepath)
              print (subdir+os.sep+new_name)
              os.rename(filepath, subdir+os.sep+new_name)
```

However when os.rename is executed I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kushal\Desktop\final_earthquake\sikkim_demo\demo_sikkim_victor\sort_inner_wav.py", line 23, in <module>
    os.rename(filepath, subdir+os.sep+new_name)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Users\\kushal\\Desktop\\final_earthquake\\demonstration_sikkim\\wav\\test\\01\\My recording #5.wav' -> 'C:\\Users\\kushal\\Desktop\\final_earthquake\\demonstration_sikkim\\wav\\test\\01\\01_test_02.wav'
```

Most likey It is trying to rename the same file twice instead of renaming each file once from the subfolder

The output:

```
C:\Users\kushal\Desktop\final_earthquake\demonstration_sikkim\wav\test\01\My recording #1.wav
C:\Users\kushal\Desktop\final_earthquake\demonstration_sikkim\wav\test\01\01_test_01.wav
C:\Users\kushal\Desktop\final_earthquake\demonstration_sikkim\wav\test\01\My recording #1.wav
C:\Users\kushal\Desktop\final_earthquake\demonstration_sikkim\wav\test\01\01_test_02.wav
C:\Users\kushal\Desktop\final_earthquake\demonstration_sikkim\wav\test\01\My recording #6.wav
C:\Users\kushal\Desktop\final_earthquake\demonstration_sikkim\wav\test\01\01_test_01.wav
C:\Users\kushal\Desktop\final_earthquake\demonstration_sikkim\wav\test\01\My recording #6.wav
C:\Users\kushal\Desktop\final_earthquake\demonstration_sikkim\wav\test\01\01_test_02.wav
C:\Users\kushal\Desktop\final_earthquake\demonstration_sikkim\wav\test\02\My recording #3.wav
C:\Users\kushal\Desktop\final_earthquake\demonstration_sikkim\wav\test\02\02_test_01.wav
C:\Users\kushal\Desktop\final_earthquake\demonstration_sikkim\wav\test\02\My recording #3.wav
C:\Users\kushal\Desktop\final_earthquake\demonstration_sikkim\wav\test\02\02_test_02.wav
C:\Users\kushal\Desktop\final_earthquake\demonstration_sikkim\wav\test\02\My recording #4.wav
C:\Users\kushal\Desktop\final_earthquake\demonstration_sikkim\wav\test\02\02_test_01.wav
C:\Users\kushal\Desktop\final_earthquake\demonstration_sikkim\wav\test\02\My recording #4.wav
C:\Users\kushal\Desktop\final_earthquake\demonstration_sikkim\wav\test\02\02_test_02.wav
C:\Users\kushal\Desktop\final_earthquake\demonstration_sikkim\wav\test\03\My recording #5.wav
C:\Users\kushal\Desktop\final_earthquake\demonstration_sikkim\wav\test\03\03_test_01.wav
C:\Users\kushal\Desktop\final_earthquake\demonstration_sikkim\wav\test\03\My recording #5.wav
C:\Users\kushal\Desktop\final_earthquake\demonstration_sikkim\wav\test\03\03_test_02.wav
C:\Users\kushal\Desktop\final_earthquake\demonstration_sikkim\wav\test\03\My recording #6.wav
C:\Users\kushal\Desktop\final_earthquake\demonstration_sikkim\wav\test\03\03_test_01.wav
C:\Users\kushal\Desktop\final_earthquake\demonstration_sikkim\wav\test\03\My recording #6.wav
C:\Users\kushal\Desktop\final_earthquake\demonstration_sikkim\wav\test\03\03_test_02.wav
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have inner `while` loop, that cause the problem, it will use same `filepath` multiple times, replace it with `if` condition like this:

```
import os
name = 'test'

rootdir = r'C:\Users\kushal\Desktop\final_earthquake\demonstration_sikkim\wav\test'

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    y=1
    for file in files:
        filepath = subdir+os.sep +file
        if filepath.endswith('.wav'):

            split_dir = subdir.split(os.sep)
            print split_dir

            f_name, f_ext=(os.path.splitext(file))

            new_1 = split_dir[7]

            new_name= (new_1 +'_' + 'test_' + str(y).zfill(2) + f_ext)
            y+=1
            if y>3:
                break
            print (filepath)
            print (subdir+os.sep+new_name)
            os.rename(filepath, subdir+os.sep+new_name)
```

Comment: Thank you Tiny D.

Comment: @choman actually you don't need that `if` condition if all sub-folders contain only two files. In case if you want to modify your program in a way that it handles all files in all sub-folders, then you don't need that `if` conditions. my solution would make your program more flexible.

Comment: one more thing, having statement like `new_1 = split_dir[7]` is inflexible and not the best way to achieve what you want here. you should rather use, `new_1 = split_dir[len(split_dir) - 1]`.

Comment: @WasiAhmad . i understand now. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have two for loops which is understandable but why there is an inner while loop? I guess, you added that while loop because you mentioned that, `Each sub folder has 2 wav files`.

The second for loop (`for file in files:`) and the inner while loop (`while y < 3:`) is actually causing the error. The second for loop is already iterating over all the files, so, you don't need that inner while loop.

Modify your program without the inner while loop as follows.

```
import os
rootdir = './test'

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    y = 1
    for file in files:
        filepath = subdir + os.sep + file
        if filepath.endswith('.wav'):
            split_dir = subdir.split(os.sep)
            f_name, f_ext = os.path.splitext(file)
            new_name= split_dir[len(split_dir) - 1] +'_' + 'test_' + str(y).zfill(2) + f_ext
            y = y + 1
            print (filepath)
            print (subdir + os.sep + new_name)
            os.rename(filepath, subdir + os.sep + new_name)
```

It outputs (in my scenario):

```
./test\01\yy.wav
./test\01\01_test_01.wav
./test\01\xx.wav
./test\01\01_test_02.wav
./test\02\yy.wav
./test\02\02_test_01.wav
./test\02\xx.wav
./test\02\02_test_02.wav
```